# Install PostgreSQL using source code or using apt-get?

Tags: postgresql, installation, ubuntu

I want to install PostgreSQL on a server that runs Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

I understand that I have two options:

1. Install PostgreSQL using the [source code distribution](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.4.1/)
2. Install PostgreSQL using `apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` with these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).

Which option should I use?

- Will there be a difference in the outcome?
- Will both options result in the same set up and configuration (assuming I choose the default installation with option #1)?
- Is there a situation where I would prefer option #1 over option #2 and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install from **apt-get** you will be able to use **apt-get upgrade** option later and other **apt-get** build in options (available from Ubuntu). 
Furthermore **apt-get** installs binaries and manages their versions. You just install and nothing more.

Installing from source gives you the ability to do a more detailed installation. (You can customize the build and installation process with command line options connected to `./configure` [PARAMETERS LIST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/install-procedure.html).) It's useful if you need a feature that can be enabled only by compiling the package yourself. Next thing is that installation from source may not be visible to **apt-get** commands so you may not be able to use them.

But if you need to install Postgres stable version without any specialized functionalities use **apt-get** option.

Comment: Is it possible to make the installation performed using the source code distribution visible to `apt-get upgrade` in retrospect? Or is this something that the user doesn't really have any control over?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've been looking for howto's and didn't found anything. But in my opinion it's not possible becouse You compile your own copy customized to your needs and source versions are rather prepared to use without apt-get and are supported with their own update/reinstall mechanisms. One more thing apt-get don't give you ability to tune up package as many as source allows so even if You would like to import source installed package to apt-get how it would be possible to handle changes that are available to make from source level but not from apt-get level? :)

Answer (score 0):

*For the purposes of this post, Ubuntu is used interchangeably with Debian.*

PostgreSQL has a ton of dependencies. Building PostgreSQL means installing the headers for a lot of things. Alternatively, you can build those things too by yourself, but then down the rabbit hole you go. You can find a list of those things using `apt-get depends postgresql-9.5`

```
libgssapi-krb5-2
libldap-2.4-2
libpam0g
libssl1.0.0
libxml2
tzdata
ssl-cert
locales
```

Moreover, if you build PostgreSQL, then you'll have to build all of these things yourself independently if you ever need them.. (list generated with `apt-cache rdepends postgresql-9.5`

```
postgresql-9.5-dbg
postgresql-pltcl-9.5
postgresql-plpython3-9.5
postgresql-plpython-9.5
postgresql-plperl-9.5
postgresql-contrib-9.5
postgresql-9.5-dbg
postgresql-pltcl-9.5
postgresql-plpython3-9.5
postgresql-plpython-9.5
postgresql-plperl-9.5
postgresql-comparator
postgresql-9.5-slony1-2
postgresql-9.5-repmgr
postgresql-9.5-repack
postgresql-9.5-python3-multicorn
postgresql-9.5-python-multicorn
postgresql-9.5-prioritize
postgresql-9.5-preprepare
postgresql-9.5-prefix
postgresql-9.5-powa
postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2
postgresql-9.5-plv8
postgresql-9.5-plsh
postgresql-9.5-plr
postgresql-9.5-plproxy
postgresql-9.5-pllua
postgresql-9.5-pgtap
postgresql-9.5-pgrouting
postgresql-9.5-pgq3
postgresql-9.5-pgpool2
postgresql-9.5-pgmp
postgresql-9.5-pgmemcache
postgresql-9.5-pgfincore
postgresql-9.5-pgextwlist
postgresql-9.5-partman
postgresql-9.5-orafce
postgresql-9.5-mysql-fdw
postgresql-9.5-mimeo
postgresql-9.5-ip4r
postgresql-9.5-debversion
postgresql-9.5-citus
postgresql-9.5-asn1oid
pg-rage-terminator-9.5
glom-utils
glom
```

On top of all that, your distribution will provide

- upgrades to newer versions of PostgreSQL when new releases come out. And, not just access to those upgrades, but they'll show up with one-click upgrade, and through whatever notification systems you in the desktop environment or at the command line. Ubuntu provides them in motd-messages and taskbar-applications.
- and, security patches for the version that they've *frozen*. In some cases the distribution may even back-port the security patches when the database drops support.

As to configuration, both versions will be configured slightly differently. As it relates to Ubuntu,

- Ubuntu installs by default to a path that includes the source-distribution's version.
- Ubuntu comes with different stock utilities that help you manage this

For a list of the management utilities provided by Ubuntu/Debian and their differences see this question,

- [What administration utilities does Ubuntu and Debian package with PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/189512/2639)