# script breaks my ability to run psql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pg-hba.conf

I've successfully installed postgres on my Ubuntu machine.  I am running a script for a website I am working on, here is the relevant code:

```
apt-get -y install postgresql libpq-dev
su postgres <<EOF
    createuser app
    createdb ultimaterehab
EOF
PG_HBA=$(su postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'SHOW hba_file'")
```

When executed this script gives the error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database "template1", SSL off
```

and when I try running psql I get a similar error:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "robin", database "robin", SSL off
```

I have tried editing the pg_hba.conf file to add the hosts but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> PG_HBA=$(su postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'SHOW hba_file'")

That seems potentially problematic.

- That line above shows `createdb ultimaterehab`. That line doesn't however connect to the `ultimaterehab` database. It connects to the default database.
- Debian/Ubuntu already does the setting up for the right pg_hba. You don't have to do anything whatsoever. If you absolutely need the location of the pg_hba file, which you do not need, you'd be better of [working with the system utility `pg_conftool`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158507/2639) to get that location: `pg_conftool show hba_file`.

Moreover, ubuntu doesn't use `su`, it uses `sudo`.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser app
sudo -u postgres createdb ultimaterehab
```

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get the same error when I do sudo (and su does work in Ubuntu), I still get errors when I run psql.

Comment: @RobinReborn in Ubuntu root is locked by default and so is the `postgres` user. The only way that would work is if you manually unlocked the `postgres` user (don't do that, it's another vector for attack).